# SilverStripe draft content status

Tags: silverstripe

Is there an easy way to identify draft content when viewing draft pages/content on my website? I want the ability to identify draft content and style it differently to published content.

I was hoping to find something like:

```
<% if $status == 'draft' %>
...
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: I think the better-navigator module could come in handy? https://github.com/jonom/silverstripe-betternavigator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SilverStripe pages are stored in `SiteTree` and `SiteTree_Live` tables. The former table contains draft content (internally called as Stage stage), and the later contains published content (Live stage). `SiteTree_versions` table contains all modified versions of the page.

When you request a page in production, it is read from Live stage by default. When you see preview in the CMS you can switch between stages.

You can get Versioned reading stage as following

```
<% if $CurrentReadingMode = 'Stage.Stage' %>
    Draft content
<% end_if %>

<% if $CurrentReadingMode = 'Stage.Live' %>
    Published content
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: That is handy but I was looking for a status on a page by page basis (ie, this page is not published)

Comment: There is no such field or method that would return you a state. You can create your own method that may check 1. the page was never published, 2. the draft page version was modified after it was published. Both cases would result in your 'not published' state. Which case do you really want to handle?

Comment: You original question is how to identify draft content, that is covered in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have mixed content being displayed on some pages (when logged in) some of it is published and some of it is draft/stage your comments have helped me understand what I needed to know so I will write something to look at publish & modification dates.

Comment: @Dan, how do you mix content on the page? Usually it is done with modules `silverstripe/widgets` and `sheadawson/silverstripe-blocks`. There is a new feature in development by SilverStripe to manage dependent content (media and embeddable pages).

Comment: On the parent page I am looping through child pages (of which some are in draft) and displaying certain pieces of content from each child. eg 
<% loop $ChildrenOf(Jobs) %>

Comment: With one loop you are reading from one (current) stage only. Change the stage and fetch children with `foreach` and store in ArrayList (you will get $draftChildren and $publishedChildren), then merge them into one list (ArrayList) and you will know what child is published already.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at the https://github.com/jonom/silverstripe-betternavigator module which shows a nice red (draft) or green (live) status bar (and a handy menu for e.g. editing this page) in the right upper corner:

[image: Demo image taken from the module's page]

Just install it using composer and put `$BetterNavigator` somewhere in your template(s). If your website uses caching, make sure BetterNavigator's output is excluded.

You can also configure it so that it's just shown when you're in dev mode or logged in.

I normally use something like this to avoid showing it to everyone when I'm in dev mode:

```
<% if $CurrentUser %>
    $BetterNavigator
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this too!